# Using ReferenceArrayInput with a none-flat array

Tags: react-admin

I have a record that looks like so:

```
Item {
   itemId: 1,
   categories: [{id: 123, categoryId: 657, itemId: 1}, ...]
}
```

(The item is pulled from rest service based on nestjsx/crud, mostly automatic, and i really want to avoid any changes there.)

ReferenceArrayInput is expecting a flat array, with direct reference to the ids. {categories: [657, ...]}

I'm looking for a way to tell him to look at a nested object property.
Or a hook, that will let me transform the records to the appropriate format.

For the visual part, i intend to use AutocompleteArrayInput